# Angular2 unable to return items from the mock service

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am writing unit test cases for Angular5 application. I am calling one function loadscopesdata() as below.

```
loadScopesData() {
        this.scopeService.getScopesByTenantId(this._searchText, this._onlyActive).subscribe(results => this.onScopesDataLoadSuccessful(results), error => this.onScopesDataLoadFailed(error));
    }
```

Which calls below service.

```
getScopesByTenantEndpoint<T>(searchText: string, onlyActive: boolean): Observable<T> {
        var scopes = localStorage.getItem('scopeObject');
        if (scopes) {
            return Observable.create(scopes);
        }
        else {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
    }
```

Whenever above code executed, It always returns control into onScopesDataLoadFailed. Can someone help me to figure it out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik Observable.create is mostly used to tell how the value will be passed to the subscriber, you already have your value and don't want to process somethig special, so can you try to simply use `return Observable.of(scopes)` instead.

**[With Observable.create()]**

```
getScopesByTenantEndpoint<T>(searchText: string, onlyActive: boolean): Observable<T> {
    return Observable.create(observer=>{
        const scopes = localStorage.getItem('scopeObject');

        //If you want to throw an err
        if(!scopes){
            throw 'no scope given'
        }

        observer.next(scopes);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. If i add Obseravle.of then i am getting error Observable<string> is not assignable to type Observable<T>

Comment: This function really need to be generic ? don't you always send an observable of "scopes" type (string typed until you parse it )? otherwise you can  keep your Observable.create , I give you another sample of code you can try